# Memory leak while running WMI query to Win32_PageFileUsage class on Server 2008 SP2

Tags: c#, wmi

Running WMI query against Win32_PageFileUsage class causes a memory leak. In my situation it is being done to 200 servers every 5 minutes. After about 3 hours the memory leak is nearly 10 GB. I think it is somehow relaited to that fact, that the pagefile does not exist. The value is "0". Here is my code:

```
...
ObjectQuery pageFileUsageQuery = 
        new ObjectQuery("SELECT AllocatedBaseSize, CurrentUsage FROM Win32_PageFileUsage");
m_PageFileUsageSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, pageFileUsageQuery);
...
var pageFileUsageCollection = m_PageFileUsageSearcher.Get();
double currentUsage = 0;
double maxSize = 0;

foreach (ManagementBaseObject managementBaseObject in pageFileUsageCollection)
{
        string result = managementBaseObject["CurrentUsage"].ToString();
        currentUsage += double.Parse(result);
}
```

The system is Windows Server 2008 SP2. Maybe somebody has any ideas?

Comment: I think this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896282/c-sharp-using-clause-fails-to-call-dispose/11896367#11896367

Answer (score 1):

`ManagementObjectSearcher` implements `IDisposable`(as does `ManagementObjectCollection` and `ManagementBaseObject`). You should dispose of these... perhaps with well placed `using` statements.

```
ObjectQuery pageFileUsageQuery = 
        new ObjectQuery("SELECT AllocatedBaseSize, CurrentUsage FROM Win32_PageFileUsage");
using(m_PageFileUsageSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, pageFileUsageQuery))
{
    ...
    using(var pageFileUsageCollection = m_PageFileUsageSearcher.Get())
    {
        double currentUsage = 0;
        double maxSize = 0;

        foreach (ManagementBaseObject managementBaseObject in pageFileUsageCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                string result = managementBaseObject["CurrentUsage"].ToString();
                currentUsage += double.Parse(result);
            }
            finally
            {
                managementBaseObject.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: :( Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: No success. I've disposed all objects and memory add on every cycle by 8kB. See the same problem by this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922601/wmi-memory-leak-solution

Answer (score 0):

As per comment above by michael-graczyk, there is a bug in the Dispose of …

Calling **GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() once is enough to fix it**

though we do not consider it a solution really, just a workaround.