# Using clause fails to call Dispose?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, using

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to target .NET 4.0 Client Profile. I have a C# class to detect when a given process starts/terminates. For this the class uses a ManagementEventWatcher, which is initialised as below; `query`, `scope` and `watcher` are class fields:

```
query = new WqlEventQuery();
query.EventClassName = "__InstanceOperationEvent";
query.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
query.Condition = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name = 'notepad.exe'";

scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\CIMV2");

watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
watcher.EventArrived += WatcherEventArrived;
watcher.Start();
```

The handler for event EventArrived looks like this:

```
private void WatcherEventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    string eventName;

    var mbo = e.NewEvent;
    eventName = mbo.ClassPath.ClassName;
    mbo.Dispose();

    if (eventName.CompareTo("__InstanceCreationEvent") == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
    }
    else if (eventName.CompareTo("__InstanceDeletionEvent") == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Terminated");
    }
}
```

This code is based on [a CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/win32processusingwmi.aspx). I added the call to `mbo.Dispose()` because it leaked memory: about 32 KB every time EventArrived is raised, once per second. The leak is obvious on both WinXP and Win7 (64-bit).

So far so good. Trying to be conscientious I added a `try-finally` clause, like this:

```
var mbo = e.NewEvent;
try
{
    eventName = mbo.ClassPath.ClassName;
}
finally
{
    mbo.Dispose();
}
```

No problem there. Better still, the C# `using` clause is more compact but equivalent:

```
using (var mbo = e.NewEvent)
{
    eventName = mbo.ClassPath.ClassName;
}
```

Great, only now the memory leak is back. What happened?

Well, I don't know. But I tried disassembling the two versions with ILDASM, which are almost but not quite the same.

IL from `try-finally`:

```
.try
{
  IL_0030:  nop
  IL_0031:  ldloc.s    mbo
  IL_0033:  callvirt   instance class [System.Management]System.Management.ManagementPath [System.Management]System.Management.ManagementBaseObject::get_ClassPath()
  IL_0038:  callvirt   instance string [System.Management]System.Management.ManagementPath::get_ClassName()
  IL_003d:  stloc.3
  IL_003e:  nop
  IL_003f:  leave.s    IL_004f
}  // end .try
finally
{
  IL_0041:  nop
  IL_0042:  ldloc.s    mbo
  IL_0044:  callvirt   instance void [System.Management]System.Management.ManagementBaseObject::Dispose()
  IL_0049:  nop
  IL_004a:  ldnull
  IL_004b:  stloc.s    mbo
  IL_004d:  nop
  IL_004e:  endfinally
}  // end handler
IL_004f:  nop
```

IL from `using`:

```
.try
{
  IL_002d:  ldloc.2
  IL_002e:  callvirt   instance class [System.Management]System.Management.ManagementPath [System.Management]System.Management.ManagementBaseObject::get_ClassPath()
  IL_0033:  callvirt   instance string [System.Management]System.Management.ManagementPath::get_ClassName()
  IL_0038:  stloc.1
  IL_0039:  leave.s    IL_0045
}  // end .try
finally
{
  IL_003b:  ldloc.2
  IL_003c:  brfalse.s  IL_0044
  IL_003e:  ldloc.2
  IL_003f:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
  IL_0044:  endfinally
}  // end handler
IL_0045:  ldloc.1
```

Apparently the problem is this line:

```
IL_003c:  brfalse.s  IL_0044
```

which is equivalent to `if (mbo != null)`, so `mbo.Dispose()` is never called. But how is it possible for mbo to be null if it was able to access `.ClassPath.ClassName`?

Any thoughts on this?

Also, I'm wondering if this behaviour helps explain the unresolved discussion here: [Memory leak in WMI when querying event logs](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/158d5f4b-1238-4854-a66c-b51e37550c52/).

Comment: I strongly suspect you've misdiagnosed this. I've *never* seen a `using` statement fail. Note that your `try/finally` version won't currently compile, so this clearly isn't your real code. Are you able to post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right, try-finally fixed now.

Comment: @groverboy Not that it matters, but from the IL it appears that your `try/finally` code is also setting `mbo` to `null`, unless it is just the Debug build doing that automatically...

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk No, you're right, the original try-finally includes `mbo = null` which I think is redundant.

Comment: @groverboy  I submitted a connect entry at the link in my edit.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

At first glance, there appears to be a bug in `ManagementBaseObject`.

Here's the `Dispose()` method from `ManagementBaseObject`:

```
    public new void Dispose() 
    {
        if (_wbemObject != null) 
        {
            _wbemObject.Dispose();
            _wbemObject = null;
        } 
        base.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 
    }
```

Notice that it is declared as `new`.  Also notice that when the `using` statement calls `Dispose`, it does so with the explicit interface implementation.  Thus the parent `Component.Dispose()` method is called, and `_wbemObject.Dispose()` is never called.  `ManagementBaseObject.Dispose()` should not be declared as `new` here.  Don't believe me?  Here's a comment from `Component.cs`, right above it's `Dispose(bool)` method:

```
    ///    <para>
    ///    For base classes, you should never override the Finalier (~Class in C#) 
    ///    or the Dispose method that takes no arguments, rather you should 
    ///    always override the Dispose method that takes a bool.
    ///    </para> 
    ///    <code>
    ///    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    ///        if (disposing) {
    ///            if (myobject != null) { 
    ///                myobject.Dispose();
    ///                myobject = null; 
    ///            } 
    ///        }
    ///        if (myhandle != IntPtr.Zero) { 
    ///            NativeMethods.Release(myhandle);
    ///            myhandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    ///        }
    ///        base.Dispose(disposing); 
    ///    }
```

Since here the `using` statement calls the explicit `IDisposable.Dispose` method, the `new` Dispose never gets called.

**EDIT**

Normally I would not assume that something like this a bug, but since using `new` for `Dispose` is usually bad practice (especially since `ManagementBaseObject` is not sealed), and since there is **no comment explaining the use of `new`**, I think this is a bug.

I could not find a Microsoft Connect entry for this issue, [so I made one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757707/c-using-statement-does-not-work-on-system-management-managementbaseobject).  Feel free to upvote if you can reproduce or if this has affected you.

Comment: Nice. I did wonder whether something like explicit interface implementation was relevant here, but didn't check the details.

Comment: Last week I ran into the same problem. It is the explicit call to `IDisposable.Dispose` with `new` that is the issue.

Comment: It does look like a bug, especially when there is no comment about `new` or XML Documentation on the method.

Comment: @AMissico Yes, I submitted a connect entry for it.  Added a link in the edit.

Comment: 5 years later. .NET 4.7. and the bug is still there [ManagementBaseObject.Dispose](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/managementbaseobject.cs,5d4c70de6d737b90)

Comment: Having issues in .NET 4.8 as well. We avoided it by using `ManagementObjectSearcher` instead of `ManagementObject`

Answer (score 0):

This issue also causes MS Unit Test Framework to fail and hang forever at the end of running all tests (under Visual Studio 2015, update 3). Unfortunately the bug still persists as I am writing this. In my case the following code is leaking:

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
{
    ....
}
```

And what Test Framework is complaining about is about a thread not being shutdown:

> System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. **This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it**. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.

And I managed to get around it by executing the code in another thread (therefore, after the starter thread exits, *hopefully* all other threads spawned in it are closed and resources are freed appropriately):

```
Thread searcherThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    {
        ....
    }
}));
searcherThread.Start();
searcherThread.Join();
```

I am not advocating that this is the solution to the problem (as a matter of fact, spawning a thread just for this call is a horrible idea), but at least I can run tests again without needing to restart Visual Studio every time it hangs.

Comment: Are you able to get around it by using `try-finally` instead of `using` (and spawning a new thread)?

Comment: @groverboyI do not see why that should not work, in my own code, I use a `using` block since the issue is not related to `Dispose` not being called. It is called, but due to a bug it does not propagate to base classes and therefore resources in base classes leak.

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing similar problem,

calling **GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() once is enough to fix the leak**

though I am aware it is not a solution, just a workaround the bug

Comment: `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` suspends the calling thread until all objects marked for finalization have had their `Finalize` methods called. This seems likely to impact on application performance, therefore best to avoid if possible. Are you able to fix the leak by using try-finally instead of a `using` clause?

Comment: A colleague fixed it properly by looking at the .NET code, finding out where it's leaking COM objects, and then disposing of them appropriately.