# Memory leaks when using DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-leaks, directoryservices

We moved our web system to Windows authentication. After deploying it to production environment we faced memory leak. We defined it was paged pool memory leak (tag Toke) using poolmon.exe util.
During recent modification we only added 2 following methods:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;


private bool IsLoginValid(string login, string password)
{
    bool isValid = false;
    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
    {
        isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(login, password);
    }
    return isValid;
}

private bool isMemberOf(string login, string group)
{
    bool result = false;           
    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
    {
        using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, login))
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                result = user.IsMemberOf(pc, IdentityType.Name, group);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Please, help to identify the exact point of leaking and if possible provide with a workaround. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()` has memory leak.

Comment: I spent the last week and a half tracking this down, myself. 
This is absolutely the correct answer. Yes, you should be disposing everything disposable in DirectoryServices  and AccountManagement as the other answers say, but in this case the interface is not exposed to us. Unmanaged memory leaks SUCK. This was so hard to find!

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly a bug in the implementation of `PrincipalContext` and/or `UserPrincipal` causing failure to auto-dispose of an instance. I have [seen this previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896282/using-clause-fails-to-call-dispose). You can easily confirm/fix this by replacing the `using` by a `try-finally`, as below.

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
try
{
     isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(login, password);
}
finally
{
     pc.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: the `new` keyword alongside explicit interface implementation causing a try/finally call to differ from a using call. Ouch. To check if this is the case, simply add an explicit cast in the finally block and see if the behavior is different: `((IDisposable)pc).Dispose();`

Comment: Thank you but I found that method `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()` has memory leak.